# Read bare repo files on the fly

Tags: c#, git, git-bare

Is there a way of reading the files of a bare repo? For instance, I want to analyze each file and extract some features from a repository but without checking out the entire repo locally.

P.S: ideally, want to use C# for this

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. There are no files in a bare repo. You can't checkout a whole repo, just a branch. What features are you trying to extract?

Comment: Some file analyze. The thing is, I have multiple projects, and the projects are huge, I don't want to have them programatically checked-out because this will take a lot of time.. I was thinking if there is a way of "on the fly" checking out without having previously checked out on local machine. Just like "storing" them in memory temporarily. And yea, I'm talking about a specific branch

Comment: Sure. Just checkout into a RAM drive. I don't think there's any other supported approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do, but there are two main methods to extract data directly from a bare repository:

- Use `git cat-file -p` to extract object data.

  This method is simple and easy but has one non-obvious drawback: no `.gitattributes` style filtering occurs.  (The obvious drawback is that you must name objects without being able to just look them up in the file system using OS routines.  However, `git cat-file` *does* use all the usual `git rev-parse` rules, so you can simply `git cat-file -p branch:path/to/file` if you know the name of the branch and the file's path.)
- Supply a work tree.

  For instance, `git --work-tree=/some/where checkout branch` works even with a bare repository: the `--work-tree` provides the top level of the work tree.  The one (or two depending on how you count) non-obvious drawback(s) here is/are that checking out a specific commit modifies the bare repository's index and `HEAD` (current branch / commit).  The index itself may or may not be in use in any other way; if not, this is not an issue, and if so, you may want to use an alternate index (via environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE`).  The `HEAD` is used implicitly by new `git clone` operations (if this particular bare clone is used as a source for other clones).